# android emulator does not recognize Hebrew font

Tags: android

android emulator does not recognize hebrew font where my phone does 
how do I install the Hebrew font on my emulator .

Comment: They haven't invented a font yet.

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417427/changing-the-android-emulator-locale-automatically

Comment: mcandre - there is no mention of 'hebrew' on that page, nor a pointer to a font installer. comments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android [does not support Hebrew](http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-2.2.html#locs), or any RTL languages, at this time. It is something they are working on, but I would not expect it until 2011.

Comment: how come it does support hebrew on my device (milestone) therefore it does support Hebrew the thing is how to make my emulator understand it too !!!

Comment: @yoav.str: You would have to ask Motorola what they did for Hebrew. Android *itself* does not support Hebrew, or any RTL languages, at this time. Hence, the Android emulator does not ship with Hebrew translations of any messages. The Droid series of fonts have at least some Hebrew glyphs, so if you use Hebrew Unicode strings, they should show up fine in your application.