# Changing Locale in Android Emulator

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, locale

I'm just starting to learn Android development. I have included a EditText component in my view and started the emulator in Eclipse.

When I type in the Textbox, the auto suggestions are coming up in Chinese language but I want to change this to English.

How do I change this Locale and Android Emulator?

I'm using the Android 2.1 for development.

Comment: On the Google emulator, you can set the language on the command line, when you launch the emulator. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417427/changing-the-android-emulator-locale-automatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No Need to change local, just long press on the EditText widget, on the popup menu select input method, and change to the android keyboard.

Answer (score 15):

I am using the emulator with Android 4.2 + 4.3 and there is an app to set the locale called "Custom Locale".

Start emulator -> Launcher -> Custom Locale
=> Select the desired language from the list
=> Confirm with e.g "Select 'de_DE'"

Comment: This is still true and is the correct answer in how to change the local in the emulator.

Comment: The region specifications (e.g. en_GB) often do not work properly in the emulator when using this method (uses the "en" resource, not the "en-rGB" resource), but do work when using the Language & Input (or Language & Keyboard) settings option like @Maaalte posted

Comment: I don't have it with SDK 28.

Comment: FYI with API 28:

Settings > Languages & Input > Language, change

Answer (score 7):

My solution is to use preinstalled on android emulator "Custom locale" application. Simply send intent with extra language parameter to it as below:

```
adb shell am broadcast -a com.android.intent.action.SET_LOCALE --es com.android.intent.extra.LOCALE EN
```

More information here - [prepare android emulator for UI test automation.](https://testyour.app/blog/emulator)

Comment: The only answer i found that makes it from the command line, this is perfect because i only have ssh access to the build machine and emulators there only, thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

I'm using 2.3.3, but it should be similar:

Start emulator -> Launcher -> Settings -> Language & keyboard -> Select language