# How do I restart an android emulator?

Tags: android, adb

I'm basically trying to do this:
[Changing the Android emulator locale automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417427/changing-the-android-emulator-locale-automatically)

Everything works up until 'start'.  the emulator starts to boot but keeps loading at the shimmering 'ANDROID' screen forever.  I must be missing something...  How can I restart the emulator from ADB?

Okay, I should be more specific.

I am trying to do this from the command line using adb.  I can use adb to setprop and I can stop the emulator. When I try doing 'start' in the adb shell, the emulator does begin to boot, but it never returns to the lock screen.

Comment: are you 'start'ing by using the CLI? `emulator -avd my_avd -prop persist.sys.language=en -prop persist.sys.country=GB`

Comment: That would avoid messing with the System Image

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this will work:

- Clear/Wipe the AVD to defaults or create a new one.
- Start the [AVD/Emulator from the CLI](https://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html) with the following command

  ```
  emulator -avd my_avd -prop persist.sys.language=en -prop persist.sys.country=GB
  ```

change as needed. That way you are not messing with the system image which can cause hangs/crashes. And you can easily set it on boot for a variety of Locales.

Comment: I think I will end up doing something like this.  The only downside is that when I am changing language/country again I have to totally kill the emulator every time.  Which I guess isn't so bad.

Comment: @jeff Right, well it's either kill it and start from the CLI this way, or set it with ADB and restart it...so, pretty much the same pain I guess. IMO just a little easier from the CLI one-liner.

Comment: Is there a way to "Clear/Wipe the AVD" via the command line?

Answer (score 152):

In Android Studio go to:

1. `Tools > Android > AVD Manager`
2. Select your emulator device
3. Click "Cold boot now" to restart, or "Wipe data" to factory reset

Comment: Assumes Android Studio is installed.

Comment: I think using "Cold Boot" would be better option!

Comment: @Shukant Pal Couls you describe what „Cold Boot“ is and how it works?

Comment: In the menu where you find "wipe data", you also find "cold boot". It starts the emulator as if it were shut down before (and not wake up from sleep). You usually don't loose persistent data in this process.

Comment: It says "AVD XXX is already running" which is true. How to RE-boot?

Comment: @Dims Click close button next to your emulator name.

Comment: I'm using Android Studio (2022.1.1) for Flutter, and I only have `Tools > Device Manager`. For the device I want to restart, I clicked the vertical ellipsis in the Actions column and selected **Cold Boot Now**

Comment: That doesn't work, it only gives error about it being already running.

Answer (score 105):

you can try simplest way possible will be just executing below command

```
emulator @avd_name -no-snapshot-load
```

it will clean the existing emulator and boot it as new devices. now you can see your device will work fine without any issue.

Above solution worked for perfectly.

Comment: But it cannot restart a device. It will complain the device is already running

Comment: `emulator @Nexus_5X_API_23 -no-snapshot` is enough

Comment: I didnt know @ was required to be prefixed... this also worked: emulator -avd Nexus_6_API_30 -no-snapshot-load

Comment: Use `emulator -list-avds` to get the list of avds on your machine

Answer (score 94):

You asked how to restart the emulator from ADB. But the title is framed in a way that pops the question up when searching about restarting it from the UI as well.

One option could be (but it depends on which tooling you are using and may not be available for all emulators/environments) is to **tap and hold** the **Power button** and then a menu will pop up with a Restart option in it.

[image]

---

This was a long-standing default behavior, but since Android 12 / API 31 it tries to open the Google Assistant instead (even when there's no such thing on emulators without Google APIs or Google Play ). The old behavior can be reverted by going to *Settings > System > Gestures > "Press and hold power button"* to bring up the menu in the screenshot.

Comment: Works for me !! (Windows 7 - Android-Studio 3)

Comment: Works on Linux as well. This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: @Deepak Not really. It doesn't work if the emulator OS is freezed as in my case. I had to wipe the saved state

Comment: Unfortunately now it opens the "Google Assistant" instead. How do we do restart the simulator now, from the UI?

Comment: @BenButterworth see edit. When long-pressing the button, Logcat displays `system_process D/WindowManager: powerLongPress: eventTime=... mLongPressOnPowerBehavior=5` which refers to `com.android.server.policy.PhoneWindowManager.LONG_PRESS_POWER_ASSISTANT` constant; here we can see what other options are possible.

Comment: Works on Mac too. I use the new updated A.S. that put the emulator in a docked window. Just press the little power icon in the docked window for 3 seconds

Answer (score 50):

To restart a running emulator I used

`adb -e reboot`

(Assuming there is only one running)

Answer (score 34):

on Android 13, when you swipe down to the notifications, and swipe down **again**, you get a power off button on the bottom right:

[image: android 13 emulator notification area]

which has the *Restart* option:

[image]

Answer (score 11):

If you are using Android Studio, you can goto the AVD Manager, Under Actions select "Cold Boot Now" to restart the emulator.  This would get rid of errors/discrepancies which might occur if the simulator's process has been abruptly closed/terminated.

Comment: Worth noting you need to kill/close the emulator first (seems obvious, but it had me stuck).

Answer (score 11):

For me, kiran-chenna's answer failed me, and the solution was to instead run:

```
emulator -avd Pixel_2_API_28 -no-cache
```

Comment: the `-no-cache` did the trick for me, easiest solution IMO thanks :)

Answer (score 11):

In my case, a cold boot was required after the emulator got stuck. It can be found in the Android Virtual Device Manager.

[image]

Comment: What is the meaning of cold boot ?

Comment: A cold boot usually refers to a system start after completely turning off the power. A warm or hot boot is when you simply restart the system after it was already running (the CPU is still hot). In this case, cold boot means completely restarting the VM instead of resuming from a stored snapshot.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68688915/6243352) provides a clearer sequence of steps for cold booting.

Answer (score 6):

Follow the following steps to restart/cold-boot your virtual device:

1. Open Android Studio
2. Click on Configure
3. Click AVD Manager
4. Click on the Dropdown on the right hand side of the virtual device.
5. Click on Cold Boot Now

You're done! The device will restart within a couple of minutes.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

2022 Android Studio Bumblebee: With the emulated device open on screen (the "Emulator" tab open), press **and hold** the power button at the top of window just as you would on a real device, and it will pop up the device's menu just as if you had held the button on the side of a real device. For example:

[image]

Comment: I had to turn off Gooogle Assistant and it worked

Answer (score 3):

If the power button (top left of Emulator) is opening up assistant:

1. Tell/type to Assistant to open "Settings" (or double drag down the battery/antenna icon on top right)
2. Search for "Power"
3. Go to "Power Gesture"
4. Turn that off!

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

In Android Studio go to Android Emulators. In the list of emulators you can see the three dots option. Just click on that option, there you can see cold boot, simply select that one.
Now you can see that your emulator is restarted as a new one.

Answer (score 2):

To start/stop or restart emulator follow these steps:

using telnet on windows machine

or localhost 5554

```
avd start start
```

or

```
avd start restart
```

or

```
avd stop
```

Answer (score 1):

Some versions of the emulator (android-7) are buggy and just hang at the shimmmera.

Try restarting it with "wipe user data" option (yes, you will have to re-run your
app or at least reinstall it).

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

emulator @avd_name -no-snapshot-load

or else Simply delete the existing AVD and try to create a new one.

By following the steps.
In Android Studio > Tools > Device Manger > Create Device

Answer (score 0):

you can restart the emulator from adb shell,
start the emulator and also adb shell in the terminal.

**start**   Starts (restarts) an emulator/device instance.
**stop**    Stops execution of an emulator/device instance.

Comment: This is what i'm trying! I'm in the terminal, i'm using adb.  I can make the prop changes, i can stop the emulator, but when I do 'start' it just never finishes booting up.

Answer (score 0):

in eclipse in the top most right u will find DDMS go i there, left side you will find Devices and in that in the last you will find a triangle downwards press that in that you will find Reset adb.