# sign apk for android app is not working

Tags: android

My android was working well until I deleted apk file then when try to run the app it gives me an error: 
Installation failed since the APK was either not signed, or signed incorrectly.
If this is a Gradle-based project, then make sure the signing configuration is specified in the Gradle build script

i tried to do it by using open module setting but it is not working then i tried to write code in build.gradle (module:app) and not working : this is the code:

[image]

Comment: I know your password now!

Comment: solve the problem and i will give u my email password also @Buddy

Comment: Did you try uninstalling your app first, and then trying to re-install it with the new signature?  Check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28884929/android-studio-installation-failed-since-apk-was-not-signed