# Installation failed since the APK was either not signed

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I just upgraded my Android Studio from 1.5 to 2.2, and now when running my App I get the error:

> Installation failed since the APK was either not signed, or signed
>   incorrectly. If this is a Gradle-based project, then make sure the
>   signing configuration is specified in the Gradle build script.

I already googled for it, and nothing worked for me, my gradle file is:

```
...
android {
    signingConfigs {
        myapp_signed {
            keyAlias 'mkey'
            keyPassword 'pwd'
            storeFile file('.../_keystore.jks')
            storePassword 'pwd'
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId '...'
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.myapp_signed
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}
...
```

Does anybody know how to solve this? Right before I got this error, I got another error, which was saying:

> Warning:Gradle version 2.10 is required. Current version is 2.2. If
>   using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in
>   C:\Users\blahblah\myproject\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties
>   to gradle-2.10-all.zip

which I solved like this ["Gradle Version 2.10 is required." Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34814368/gradle-version-2-10-is-required-error)

**EDIT:**
Even if I switch build variants back to debug, uninstall the app and try it again I get the same error.

Comment: Are you using '...'  in the file path or is that just to obscure personal info?

Comment: thats just to obsucre personal info :D

Comment: possible duplicate: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28884929/android-studio-installation-failed-since-apk-was-not-signed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me the solution was, to update all the libraries I used and update to Android 23. 
Maybe this helps somebody.

Answer (score 1):

By default, Android Studio 2.2 and the Android Plugin for Gradle 2.2 sign your app with Signature Scheme v2. add **v2SigningEnabled false** to `signingConfigs` may solve your problem.

```
signingConfigs {
      release {
        storeFile file("myreleasekey.keystore")
        storePassword "password"
        keyAlias "MyReleaseKey"
        keyPassword "password"
        v2SigningEnabled false
      }
    }
```

ref. https://developer.android.com/preview/api-overview.html#apk_signature_v2

Comment: There's nothing in the error messages that suggests this has anything to do with APK Signature Scheme v2.

Answer (score 0):

For reference, my signing configs look like this - not my real passwords :

```
 signingConfigs {
    release {
        storeFile file("keystore/release.jks")
        keyAlias "release"
        storePassword "storepass"
        keyPassword "keypass
    }

    debug {
        storeFile file("keystore/debug.jks")
        keyAlias "androiddebugkey"
        storePassword "android"
        keyPassword "android"
    }
}

 buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        zipAlignEnabled true
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }

    debug {
        minifyEnabled true
        zipAlignEnabled true
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }
}
```

Comment: just forgot to obscure some more personal info :D The gradle was auto generated by android studio, i will try it like you did though

Comment: @LucaThiede, ok updated my answer to remove reference to mismatched signingconfig name.

Comment: Yup running into exact same issue. Would be great if some google folks take time off from google I/O and fix this issue ;)

Comment: @SubodhNijsure have you found a Solution yet?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to generate a new keystore to use?
In my case, my old keystore file is not working anymore after I upgrade from gradle build tools 1.5.0 to 2.1.0
It surprise me when I try it out...

Comment: Yeah, I created a new keysrore, and it is still not working. Also it doesn't even work in the debug mode, where Android Studio uses the default keystore, and if this would be corrupted, my other Apps shouldnt work either should they?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the issue is bug us with downgrading gradle to version 2.1.0

```
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

if you still get this error even in debug mode then just **Clean** your project and **Run** again. That worked out for me

P.S: I am using Android 2.2 Beta