# Flutter : Error connecting to the server protocol

Tags: android, flutter, dart, android-emulator

I clone the code from bitbucket and run on my VS code, Every time It' through this error[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/naSbt.png)

I tried to solve this problem :
1> flutter clean
2> flutter run
but It won't be work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the exact problem,but the error is solved when I changed the emulator version to Pie,
Android : Pie
Version : API 28

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting your emulator.

[Check this link on how to restart it.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74328811/9720534)

If that doesn't work, then try creating a new one using [AVD manager](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds)

Comment: restarted multiple time It won't be work