# How to add language in Android Virtual Device

Tags: localization, android-virtual-device

I tested my app for English and Russian in AVD (Galaxy S7).

Now I need to add Hebrew support, but I wonder that in AVD no Hebrew language.

Please help me to add Hebrew in to AVD or any other solution is welcome!

Comment: Does this answer your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417427/changing-the-android-emulator-locale-automatically#2418724 ?

Comment: David, it definitely helps me alot!
Behavior of emulated device is such as hebrew locale.
It's solved my problem.
Unfortunately, most of UI still shows English, for esthetic reasons, can I do something for full Hebrew (include UI) support?