# Automated testing in Android development

Tags: android, junit, jvm, automated-tests, dalvik

I have an ordinary project with JUnit tests that are connected to the classes in my Android Project. I want my server to run some JUnit tests in my testproject everytime I commit my code from my Android Project.

Is there a best practise to do this?
So far I only managed to run the tests when they are a part of a while the JUnit tests and Android classes are separated into 2 different projects, since JUnit runs on JVM and Android in an emulator on DVM (Dalvik Virtual Machine).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/) to achieve this. I've written some articles describing this, for example [Android Continuous Integration: Build with Maven](http://dtmilano.blogspot.com/2010/01/android-continuos-integration-build.html).

To be able to run the tests some emulator instances fulfilling your project's requirement must be running on the CI server, preferably in headless mode.

[Changing the Android emulator locale automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417427/changing-the-android-emulator-locale-automatically/2418724#2418724) and [How to Get Serial Number or ID of Android Emulator After it Runs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214377/how-to-get-serial-number-or-id-of-android-emulator-after-it-runs) could also come in handy.