# How to get Android AVD name from adb device name

Tags: android, adb, adt, android-virtual-device

Using the Android SDK from the command line, I can get a list of the running devices available using:

```
./adb device
```

This gives me the serial number of available devices. How can I get the AVD name of the emulator device from that serial number (like the Eclipse ADT plugin does)?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The Eclipse plugin does it by connecting to the emulator via tcp/ip.  To connect, (for linux), type

> ~/code$ telnet localhost 5554
>   Trying ::1...
>   Trying 127.0.0.1...
>   Connected to localhost.
>   Escape character is '^]'.
>   Android Console: type 'help' for a list of commands
>   OK

Replace "5554" with whatever number comes after the hyphen when you type "adb devices" - "emulator-5554", for instance, would have telnet port 5554 open.

Then, type "avd name", hit enter, and you should see something similar to the following:

> avd name
>   GB10
>   OK

In this example the emulator's name was "GB10".

Comment: Never would have figured that out on my own. Thanks!

Comment: Is there any way to just invoke `avd name` from the command line without telnet?

Comment: Nope. The avd command only exists on the emulated device, which is why you have to telnet into it to to run "avd name"

Comment: @Kvass: Here's a hack that simplifies the process (works on OS X): `(sleep 0.5; echo 'avd name') | telnet 127.0.0.1 5554`

Answer (score 38):

Here it is:

```
> adb -s emulator-5554 emu avd name
MyDevice
OK
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `adb devices` you can see the List of devices attached.

In my case the result is:

```
List of devices attached
emulator-5554   device
```