# Getting AVD name via telnet fails

Tags: android, bash, android-virtual-device

Related questions I researched:

[How to get Android AVD name from serial number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8381998/how-to-get-android-avd-name-from-serial-number)

And we have the following solutions:

```
(sleep 0.5; echo 'avd name') | telnet 127.0.0.1 5554
```

I work on 2 OSes: OS X Yosemite, and a Debian VM. Changing the `sleep` time doesn't really matter.

I start an emulator in each system. The `adb devices` shows everything correct: `emulator-5554 device`. Now I am trying to get the name of the running emulator.

Here what happens on OS X:

```
(sleep 1; echo "avd name") | telnet 127.0.0.1 5554
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Android Console: type 'help' for a list of commands
OK
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Here what happens on Debian:

```
(sleep 1; echo "avd name") | telnet localhost 5554
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Android Console: type 'help' for a list of commands
OK
emu_19_WVGA800
OK
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

But it fails sometimes, it's not stable at all, sometimes it fails alike with OS X.

In tried also this: `{echo open 127.0.0.1 5554; sleep 1; echo "avd name"} | telnet`. This has exactly the same output: it fails on OS X and succeeds sometimes on Debian.

Please give me a hint: what's with this different behaviour? Why it is so unstable?

Answer (score 1):

After some more research, I've found that [NetCat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat) is very powerful and useful, and is present on *NIX based systems.

Here is a fast, clean, reliable solution to get the name of the running AVD:

```
echo "avd name" | nc -w 1 localhost 5554
```